# How to install Pageant or other on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, aws, putty

I'm currently trying to install Pageant on Ubuntu 16.
I'm used to use Putty for ssh and Pageant for the connexion. I've been on multiple sites and I can't find my answers:

1. How can I download Pageant?
2. I want to download Pageant, but is there another program I should use in an Ubuntu env?

I know putty is not a necessity for ssh and it was build for Windows user. Linux can achieve the same using command line, but like I said I'm used to this tool. However, if there's a way to 'imitate' putty and Pageant together, I'm open to suggestion!

(I need to use a .pem file to access my AWS servers through putty, this is why I'm stucking with Pageant.)

If any of you have a better idea to achieve this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux/Ubuntu Already has Everything you Need**

You don't need to install anything. Putty and Pageant are windoze utilities to give windoze linuxy capabilities.

To set up authentication for ssh on your linux box, you will need to work in your .ssh folder in your home folder. Here is a helpful link for setting up and understanding ssh and key based authentication:

[SSH Essentials: Working with SSH Servers, Clients, and Keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys)

You might be able to avoid a lot of setup, by exporting your keys from putty, and using them on your linux machine by following the answer here:

[How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use)

Comment: But putty and pageant give more comfort - especially if work with multiple ssh connections, connecting and disconnecting many times. mouse is faster than keyboard

Comment: -1 because it's not an answer to the question, rather an opinion on was the question necessary. Pageant gives its own functionality and the question was also - is there anything similar in Linux